# Updating magit today gives me invalid face attribute

Tags: magit

Updating magit this morning I now can't start things up, getting:

```
face-attribute: Invalid face attribute name: :extend
```

Anyone know what could cause and (hopefully!) fix this?

Comment: I don't know what causes it. Had the same trouble with a couple of packages. Spent a couple of hours this morning trying to fix it. As I'm using v27 I tried to recompile emacs with the latest changes as last resort and it worked. Still no idea of what it was causing the error.

Comment: Yes I think it's something in v27 actually - recompiling emacs not an option for me so I've gone back to emacs 26, which works with this magit, phew

Comment: Some ideas: 1) `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` to check the backtrace if any 2) Does restart Emacs help? 3) Try Emacs -Q via `M-x magit-emacs-Q-command` to see if it is reproducible.

Comment: @xuchunyang except #3 tried everything. Restarting emacs didn't help. Error happened calling some compiled code, I wasn't able to trace back the exact point between tries but it didn't appeared to be magit itself. Some of my custom code which has nothing to do with magit had the same problem, also some sexps used in org-agenda threw errors as invalid.  I recompiled all the elpa packages, but it didn't helped either. Before starting to debug more seriously I upgraded emacs code, and then problem dissapeared. if it can help anyone...

Comment: @Muihlinn Magit has code like `(and (>= emacs-major-version 27) '(:extend t))`. I don't share elpa packages across different versions of Emacs `(setq package-user-dir (concat "~/.emacs.d/elpa-" emacs-version))`. The safest way to reinstall (or recompile) a package is uninstall it, restart Emacs, then install it. I still don't understand the issue and I posted this comment just in case they are related.

Comment: Packages aren't shared, there is only an Emacs version installed. On Monday weekly upgrade a bunch of packages were downloaded. Perhaps 35. After restarting it didn't work. I did several restarts trying to isolate a common cause without success errors like this popped up from a number of packages, not only magit. Only upgraded Emacs itself to have the latest codebase for the incoming debug day, but alas it wasn't needed in the end. That's all and my 2c about it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:extend` is a new face property in the development version of Emacs 27. I still hope it won't make it into Emacs 27.1 in its current form.

Never-the-less I have updated Magit to set this attribute when necessary (i.e. only for certain faces and only when using Emacs 27). If you are using Emacs 27 but have not pulled and recompiled in a month or so, then you get this warning. Pull and recompile Emacs to fix this.